# Remove html tags apart from the image tag from the string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding remove the html tags from string apart from the image tag. Let's say we have a string like :

```
<p>MA2: Allow time for editing and other types of question revisions.<span class="AM"> <img src="img" title="{(1 if x>=0),(0 if x<0):}"style="vertical-align: middle;"> </span> <span class="AM"> </span> </p>
```

In this we only need to remove the `<p>` and `<span>` like the html tags. **But we need the image tag.**

---

Expected Result :

```
MA2: Allow time for editing and other types of question revisions.<img src="img" title="{(1 if x>=0),(0 if x<0):}" style="vertical-align: middle;">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're keeping the contents of the `<p>` tag? What if there are contents in the `<span>` tag?

Comment: @EvanKnowles We need all the contents even in span or label whatever html tags.

Answer (score 2):

> $('span').contents().unwrap();
>
> $('p').contents().unwrap();

For all elements except images:

`$('*').not('img').contents().unwrap();`

More here:

http://api.jquery.com/contents/

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/